# Best Practices for Laravel 5 Command Bus

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to refactor controllers and have taken a look at Laravel's command bus.

After reading a bunch of articles and watching a few videos, it seems that this may be a great way to refactor my controllers.

However, it also seems that I shouldn't be returning anything from a command.

> When using commands
>   you follow the Command-query separation (CQS) principle: a function is
>   either a query (i.e. it returns something) or a command (i.e. it
>   affects state). Both are mutually exclusive. So a command is not
>   supposed to return anything and a query is not supposed to modify
>   anything.
>   [source](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2015/01/some-questions-about-the-command-bus/)

I have created command `CreateCustomerCommand`:

```
namespace App\Commands;

use QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer;

use App\Commands\Command;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\SelfHandling;

class CreateCustomer extends Command implements SelfHandling
{
    private $qb;
    private $customer_service;
    private $customer;
    private $is_same_address;
    private $name;
    private $primary_phone;
    ...

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->qb = Quickbooks::Instance();
        $this->qb->ipp->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

        $this->customer_service = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

        $this->is_same_address = $request->input('customer.isSameAddress');
        $this->name = ucwords(strtolower($request->input('customer.name')));
        $this->primary_phone = $request->input('customer.primaryPhone');
    }
    ...

    /**
     * Execute the command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->customer->setDisplayName($this->name);

        ...

        $this->customer_service->add(...);



    }
}
```

Three questions regarding best practices:

1. After calling `$this->customer_service->add()`, a customer `id` is returned.  How can I send this `id` back to the controller?
2. Where would it be best to incorporate an activity log?

Activity:

```
$activity = new Activity();
$activity->event = 'Created Customer: ' . $this->name;
$activity->user = Auth::user()->name;
$activity->save();
```

Would it be best to just include this at the end of `CreateCustomerCommand`?

3. What about an event?

Event:

```
event(new CustomerWasCreatedOrUpdated);
```

I am new to application architecture and am looking for a way to keep my controllers simple and maintainable.  I would love if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, kudos to you for striving to keep your controllers "simple and maintainable". You may not always achieve this goal, but reaching towards it will more often than not pay off.

**How can I send the ID back to the controller?**

A command is a specialized case of a general service.  Your command is free to declare additional public methods that interrogate the result of changing state.  If the command were used by a CLI application, that application might do something like `echo $this->command->getAddedCustomerId()`. A web-based controller could use it similiarly.

However, the advice you quoted -- to either change state with no output or to query with output -- is sage.  If you're changing state *and* you need to know the result of changing that state, you're probably abusing a command.

As an analogy consider the Linux command "useradd", which you would invoke like `useradd -m 'Clara Barton' cbarton`.  That command runs and gives you just a success or failure indication.  But note that you *gave it the primary key*, "cbarton".  You can independently query for that key, like `grep cbarton /etc/passwd`, but importantly `useradd` didn't create an ID for you.

In summary, a command that changes state should at most tell you success or failure. If you wish to inspect the result of that state change, you should have given the command the keys necessary to locate the state change.

So what you probably want is a general service.  A command might use that service, a controller might use the service, a model might use the service.  But a service is just a general class that performs one job, and gives you the necessary API.

**Where to incorporate an activity log?**

Assuming you're not using PHP-AOP, a careful and rigorous practice for activity logging should be established up front and followed throughout the development lifecycle.

To a large extent, the location of the activity log depends upon the major architectural model of your system.  If you rely heavily on events, then a good place might be in an extension of the `Event` facade or a log event.  If you rely on DI extensively, then you might pass the Logger in code you decide needs logging.

In the specific case of a command, you would go either way, again depending upon your major architectural model.  If you eschewed events, then you would inject the logger via Laravel's normal type-hinting DI.  If you leveraged events, then you might do something like `Event::fire('log', new LogState('Blah Blah', compact ($foo, $bar)));`

That said, the most important thing is that you rely on a pluggable and configurable logging service, one that you can swap out and tweak for testing, QA, and production needs.

**What about events?**

Well, events are great.  Until they're not.  In my experience, events can really get complicated as they're, IMO, *abused* for passing data around and affecting state.

Events are like teleporters: you're going down a path, then the event fires, and suddenly you're teleported all the way across the code base and pop up in a totally different place, then you do something and get dropped right back where you were.  You have to think a certain way and be efficient at following the code when Events are at play.

If Laravel events are your first introduction to events, I would discourage you from leveraging them heavily.  Instead, I would suggest you limit them to one particular package or portion of your application until you get a feel for the power they offer, and the architectural and developmental rigor they require.

Comment: Great answer.  It seems like what I am trying to do belongs in a general service rather than a command.  I will most likely also create an activity service.  As for events, I only have one for now that asynchronously re-caches customer data if the data has changed.  Would you be able to point me in the right direction regarding general services?  Laravel Service Providers are something completely different, correct?

Comment: Yes, Laravel Service Providers are different than general service classes.  Service Providers are bootstrapping code for packages.  A general service class is just a class that does something.  I often create a `src/services` directory that contains these services.  They're small classes that do one job and do it well, and are needed in multiple places throughout the app.  The wiki page on the [Servant pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_(design_pattern)) mostly describes the idea (though I think the page is hard to read).  An activity recorder sounds like a great service.